# Unity - infinite point addition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im currently making a 3d softbody tetris game in unity and I am new to c# and unity in general. im stuck on this one problem, i feel like it could be pretty simple but I cannot seem to get it to work.
backstory: trying to implement scoring system with line detection function made with raycasting. I would prefer to use line clearing to determine score but my team member is still working on that as getting mesh slicing to work with softbodies is proving to be very difficult. So in the meantime, trying to do my part and get the points system done atleast. Right now, I have a function in my ScoreManager script (AddPoint) that just adds one point to score and displays it to the UI. Now I am calling that function in Line Detection script to use the function (IsRowFilled) which returns true if the row is full.
I am calling this function in Update...

```
public bool needPoints = true;
private void CheckRows()
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < RowSize; row++)
        {
            if(IsRowFilled(row + 1) && needPoints == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Line full - adding point");
                ScoreManager.instance.AddPoint();
                needPoints = false;

            } else
            {
                // Debug.Log("Row " + row + " is empty");
            }

        }
    }
```

Right now I am using the boolean needPoints because without it the points add infinitely once a row is full. Thats why I would prefer to use line clearing function instead of line detection as I believe the infinite point addition problem is because it keeps detecting the first row and adding a point for it?  But of course with the boolean value it only allows for only one point to get added when the first line is full and doesnt check the lines above it. Ive tried a bunch of stuff but I keep getting this infinite point addition problem. I probably need to just wait for line clearing mechanics to be done... But is it possible to add points based on line is full right now?

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.

Comment: Gotcha! Only static variable I had related to this was private static int RowSize = 20; Expectedly, didn't fix anything though.

Comment: I'm referring to you `ScoreManager.instance`...but yes this isn't an answer to your question, merely a FYI. ;)

Comment: you actually helped me solve this!!! Instead I made line detection script the instance and then called IsRowFilled in Score manager script. I think the problem with the infinite add was score was a global variable. So I made a local score variable inside my AddPoint function and then added to it when line full! Then assigned global score to the local and outputted that to UI. your comment made me think about my variables and how they could be affecting this! So thank you kind stranger!!!